# backend design:What should I store in system-push-message model?

Tags: django, web, model, message, backend

I'am a green hands in web backend and recently I have a problem about designing system-message module in my django project.

Consideration of expansibility, I don't store indexes using ForeignKey or concrete fields of exact object because it's difficult to predict what messages will carry. Then I can only make it in a easy way. I add four fields:`receiver_id`, `time`,`readflag` and `content`(str). But `content` is `text/html` type and it's inflexible to modify in frontend.

Thus I wanner see the common way to solve this problem.

Sincere thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using [`django-messages`](http://django-messages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or any of the others listed at [djangopackages.com](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/messaging/)?

Comment: hah~囧rz...I don't realize I am reinventing the wheel...thanks a lot!!But I am still curious about the way to solve it.

Comment: Since they are open source, you can [look at their `models.py`](https://github.com/arneb/django-messages/blob/master/django_messages/models.py) to see how they are storing messages.

Comment: Hmmm OK,I will~ Thanks for your help!^_^